# Average of ongoing durations

Tags: survival, mean

Suppose I run a community center and I want to find the average length of time that someone is a rec center member. It is straightforward to do this with people who have already cancelled their accounts, but I'm not sure how to handle the data of people who still have accounts.

For example, suppose the average duration of people who have cancelled is 500 days. But when I take the average of *all* account durations (assuming today is the "end date" for current members) that number become to 1000. The obvious problem with this is it is possible for a current member to cancel tomorrow or they may cancel in 10 years. Furthermore, someone who joined yesterday will have a duration of 1 day, which is not accurate.

My hunch is that this involves predicting when current members will cancel, but that seems to add several layers of complexity to this (seemingly) simple question.

I apologize in advance if this has been asked. I did try searching, but it's possible I don't know the correct terminology for this concept.

Comment: Look into survival analysis. Browse a bit and then you can form a more specific question.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be the keyword I was missing. I'll post a more direct question if I need more help.